# How do I control the width of the overflow menu?

Tags: codenameone

The Overflow menu is very narrow. It's not even an inch wide, for a screen that's more than two inches. I would think it would try to size itself to accommodate the text and icons of the the menu commands, but it seems to be a fixed size, and I need it to be a bit wider. Is there a way to force it to resize itself for the menus? Or is there a way to set its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides setting padding and font size to the commands style there is another hidden behavior in the overflow menu.

The overflow menu is built on top of `List` which is a bad decision based on legacy code. Because of that sizing the list width is usually done thru the rendering prototype object which isn't accessible unless you inherit `Toolbar`.

This code:

```
Form f = new Form("AAAA", BoxLayout.y()); 

f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("a"));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi a", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("aaa"));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi aaa", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("aaaaa"));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi aaaaa", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("aaaaaaa"));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi aaaaaaa", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("aaaaaaaaa"));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi aaaaaaaaa", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("aaaaaaaaaaa"));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi aaaaaaaaaaa", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("aaaaaaaaaaaaa"));

f.show();
```

Produces this:

[image]

Notice the menu grows until the 5th element where is stops. That's because list by default checks the first 5 elements only for preferred size when we don't have a rendering prototype.

The right solution is to throw away the list and use a proper container which will improve a bunch of other things in the `Toolbar` but this requires some work.